# Build Cordova project in Xcode: missing icon

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, app-store

I'm trying to build a cordova (version 4) based project with Xcode (for iOS). Everything is working until the process to validate the archive.
I'm build for iOS v > 7 and always have the error:

> "iTunes Store operation failed: missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone of exactly '120x120' pixels in .png format for iOS versions.

The thing is, there is such file, as shows in the printscreen!
[printscreen with Xcode nav, with the Resources/icons folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNtkd.png)

I'm sure the file icon-120.png is exactly 120x120px (I have saved several times it, using Photoshop, Fireworks, https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon plugin).

I don't know if I have to configure anything else. I have also reloaded Xcode, nothing seems to work by now :-/

Comment: Is your 120x120 file also referenced in config.xml?

Comment: @QuickFix changing the config.xml didn't make any effect. I had to change the Info.plist file (it's a kind of XML) and add the desired icons into CFBundleIconFiles. Now it works. But I found that it is really confusing the configuration from a cordova project. Somethings you change (following the official docs) don't work, you have to change it manually inside the XCode. It's a little bit frustrating :/-

Answer (score 1):

go to Xcode, view -> Navigators -> Show Project Navigrator

Go to Resources in the project navigator

Click on Image-xcassets

you will see all the icons that the xcode is using to build. Most likely, you will a lot of warning sign attached to each icon. read the required size from each warning. right click -> go to finder, then change the icon size from preview app as required. 
repeat for each icon with warning till you resolve all of them.